# Why Python socket-io server works with JavaScript but not with Android Studio

Tags: javascript, python, java, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am currently running a Python Flask-SocketIO server that connects perfectly to my JavaScript Client. I am using the socketio android example chat app to write the Android code, the Python server it won't connect.

**How can I connect to the Ptyhon Flask-SocketIO server with Android?**

**Android code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://127.0.0.1:420");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSocket.connect();

        String mUsername = "FatCat";
        String message = "Hallo";
        mSocket.emit("new_message", "{\"username\": \"" + mUsername + "\", \"message\":\""+ message +"\"}");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mSocket.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:420");
        socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('new_message', {username: "FatCat", message:"gg"});
        });
    </script>
```

**Python code:**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "key"
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("x.html")

@socketio.event
def connect():
    print("connected")

@socketio.event
def new_message(data):
    print({"username": data["username"], "message": data["message"]})
    socketio.emit("new_message", {"username": data["username"], "message": data["message"]})

@socketio.on("new_message")
def new__message(data):
    print("on")
    print({"username": data["username"], "message": data["message"]})
    socketio.emit("new_message", {"username": data["username"], "message": data["message"]})

@socketio.event
def disconnect():
    print("disconnected")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, port=420,debug=True)
```

There is no error but it send nothing to the server.

Comment: The reference Socket.IO implementation is the JavaScript one, so I test against that. The Android client that you are using can be incompatible with the version of Socket.IO that you are using in the server. Check the server logs to see if there are any clues.

Comment: Ok I will do this!

Comment: Where are you testing your code? If your android code is not being tested on the same machine as the python flask server, your addresses are invalid since you use the loopback address 127.0.0.1

Try using your LAN address (usually starting with 192.168.x.x) if your devices are on the same LAN otherwise you might need actual IP addresses to test this application out.

I am not sure if the Android VM on your computer shares the same loopback as the one on your computer, so might be worth trying the LAN addresses